# select from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have table `AA`  with Columns 
`A  B  C` with values `1,a,a`

Table `BB` with `A,B,C` with values `2,b,b`

if i `select B=a and C=a` i want to get o/p as  Column `A` with Value `1`

or

if i `select B=b and C=b` i want to get o/p Column `A` with Value `2`

I want single  query for this

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT a FROM AA WHERE B = 'something' AND C = 'something')
UNION ALL
(SELECT a FROM BB WHERE B = 'something' AND C = 'something')
```